# Is it possible to load Jquery in the body of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, external-script

I am using code-igniter, and some of my views require jquery. Because they must be used in multiple places they must call jquery in their file, however since they are referencing an external file, calls to $(document.ready) are evaluated before loading jquery and therefore fail. Is it possible to put jquery in the body and still have it load before an javascript is evaluated. Or alternatively, is the some way to pass the fact that jquery is required back through code-igniter into the headers, which were callled before the file in question.

In a view:

```
echo $this->import->js('jquery.js','jquery');
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$(\'div#login.rounded\').corner();})
</script>';
```

You can view the page at: http://formulator.codingproject.net/content/login/

**NOTE** This page actually resides on my home machine, so it is expected that the recaptcha fails.

Comment: I have attempted it and not found a way. I'll be interested to see if someone else has.

Comment: I'm not familiar with codigniter, but this seems interesting... what's the difference between `$this->import->js('jquery.js','jquery')` and just `echo`-ing the entire `<script>` manually?

Comment: Sorry, import is a special object I built so that I wouldn't write reference to the same file multiple times. In short, it checks to make sure the file hasn't already been used and then returns the script, but it shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: I've added a link... can anyone see why its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer is yes. you can load the `jQuery.js` in your `body`. But you have to write your script tags only after `jQuery.js`  declaration, if not you may end up with errors :)

**PS** : please correct me If I'm wrong :)

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery should really be called in the head element. Here's how you'd do that conditionally (untested).

In your controller, each function that needs jQuery should have:

```
$data['need_jquery'] = true;
$this->load->view('header');
```

In your header view:

```
<head>
    <? if($need_jquery) { ?>
        <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" /></script>
    <? } ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Wow, that's a much better idea than mine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using PHP?  If so, create a static method that returns that string, but only if it hasn't already been included this request.  Then you can ensure that it's only being included once.

Answer (score 0):

My website is the same way.  What I do is I have one header that is loaded on all pages.  In that header I do `if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'controller')`.  Then I load jQuery and certain scripts if needed for that controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be fine if jQuery will be included in the  tag of every page, besides, you can use the minified version of jQuery which is not so heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, maybe I'm wrong. But when I view your source code and follow where the jquery file is: http://www.formulator.com/assets/scripts/jquery/jquery.js I get a "page cannot be found" error. So I'm guessing this could be the problem. Maybe the way your php outputs it isn't including the correct domain/subdomain?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Like I said it resides on my home machine, so I'll need to update it a bit to access jquery.

Comment: Alright I've fixed that. But the error persits.
PS thanks for the tip off.